# When eventStream data isn't found, my script crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x

My python script is shown below. This script reads the `line` data and sends it as a post request. Sometimes when the eventStream sends a new message containing data. It always doesn't have data for `line` So it works fine until the second example get's sent.{Which can be randomly,}

Here is a example of two events from the stream. The first one contains data from "line". The second example doesn't.

Example 1: contains data from "line"

```
data: {"ident":"8micxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls","line":[[300,161],[301,161],[301,161],[302,161],[302,161],[307,166],[307,166],[315,176],[315,176],[319,181],[319,181],[321,185],[321,185],[322,186],[322,186]],"lineColor":"db1f1f","lineWidth":"1","opacity":"75","status":"d","channel":"_index"}
```

Example 2: Doesn't Contain "line" data.

```
data: {"ident":"c4duzpz3aw3uurbmzmzxe4u43y7xiaup","status":"w","channel":"_index"}
```

So when the second eventStream message sends(example 2) My script crashes. I would like for it to constantly run and if the `"line"` data isn't found just wait unit it's found. When it's found, send the request.

My python script below:

```
import json
import requests
from sseclient import SSEClient as EventSource
url = "URL"

querystring = {"ing":"_index"}


headers = {
'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=---- 
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
'X-Requested-With': "XMLHttpRequest",
'Accept': "*/*",
'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
'Postman-Token': "a4cccbb2-ec51-4694-b198-e733f1f10e4c,ed3c968e-b8b2-4168-abef-51025096933d",
'Host': "URLHERE",
'cookie': "i=cloyfj1bio8uvxlqrkfkczqxo1pmx7m5; o=100; w=15; c=t44q; h=_-g00000____5aU00bH_GqCFXg3g_SY0gtx1J808RNApYLbO6g41X1wo____T000R01Puw3rMVU0t44q7w3F0afp4NcjXz00; a=lnpe0l; oi=qld8gxkfrzalpvqgydze7dzbm8p1r2zp",
'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
'content-length': "713",
'Connection': "keep-alive",
'cache-control': "no-cache"
}

url1 = 'http://URLHERE.com/'
for event in EventSource(url1):
if event.event == 'message':
    try:
        change = json.loads(event.data)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        print('{ident} drew {status}'.format(**change))
        payload = {'l': '{line}'.format(**change), 'c': '00ff00', 'w': '{lineWidth}'.format(**change), 'o': '100', 'f': '1', '_': 'false'}
        requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test for the existence of the `"line"` key in `change`:

```
for event in EventSource(url1):
    if event.event == 'message':
        try:
            change = json.loads(event.data)
        except ValueError:
            continue

        # no 'else' needed here, `continue` will skip to the next iteration
        print('{ident} drew {status}'.format(**change))

        # `change` is a standard Python dict so you can
        # easily test if a given key is set
        if "line" in change:
            payload = {'l': '{line}'.format(**change), 'c': '00ff00', 'w': '{lineWidth}'.format(**change), 'o': '100', 'f': '1', '_': 'false'}
            requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
```

Comment: Let's say. If a event message contains a certain, "ident" value, could I some way skip that event? So it won't read that event because the "ident" value is "true" for a example. So If the "ident" value contains a specific value, skip that event and wait for the next one.

Comment: Well yes of course why ??? You just have to test the value and take appropriate action. May I kindly suggest that you do the official Python tutorial ?